# Coulomb's Law: Determining the magnitude and direction with three charges as given

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law

It would be appreciated if someone can confirm if I am in a right path in solving this problem. The problem goes this way.

> Consider three charges on a coordinate
> system. Charge $q_1$ = +30 nC is at the origin, charge $q_2$ = −25 nC is at (0.2, 0) mm, and charge $q_3$ = +18 nC
> is at point (0.2, 0.3) mm. Find the magnitude and direction of the resultant force on $q_3$.

Based in the illustration, the connected coordinates will create a right triangle. In this case, I will solve the y-component and x-component force of these charges.

$\vec F_y$ = k$\frac{|q_2q_3|}{r^2}$ $\hat j$

$\vec F_y$ = $(8.988 x 10^9 Nm^2/C^2)$ $\frac{|(-25x10^-9)(18x10^-9)C|}{(0.0003 m)^2}$ $\hat j$

$\vec F_y$ = 0.0135 $\hat j$ N/C

---

$\vec F_x$ = k$\frac{|q_1q_2|}{r^2}$ $\hat i$

$\vec F_x$ = $(8.988 x 10^9 Nm^2/C^2)$ $\frac{|(-25x10^-9)(30x10^-9)C|}{(0.0002 m)^2}$ $\hat i$

$\vec F_x$ = 0.0337 $\hat i$ N/C

---

Then, solve for the magnitude of the force

F = $\sqrt{0.0135^2 + 0.0337^2}$ = 0.036 N/C

$tan^{-1}(\frac{0.0135}{0.0337})$ = 21.83 degrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did well on calculating both forces by Q1 and Q2. However, if you can draw the force, they are not perpendicular of each other. The force by Q2 is upward and force by Q1 is up-right. Both forces form an angle of theta, and it is not 90 degree. So, you can not use Pythagoras here to find the resultant force.

To find the resultant, you need [cosine rule](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/lcos.html).

[image]

Comment: Oh okay thank you for the correction. So, I am gonna compute also for the force between the charges q1 and q3 and then proceed to compute for the resultant using cosine law. Am I right?

Comment: @aidenFroste I just realized that your previous calculation is also wrong. You did right calculating the F32 (red force on my picture), and the direction is also right (upward, parallel to j vector, to the y direction). But for F31 (orange force), you should use the value of Q1 and Q3 (not Q1 and Q2 like what you did). Your direction for F31 is also wrong. The force is not parallel to I vector (x direction), but it is up-right direction. After you've got the value of F32, F31, and the cos(theta), then you can calculate the resultant using the cosine rule.